# Azure IoT Devices Receiving Twin Update Notifications

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I tried to receive desired properties update notifications by subscribing topic "$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/#"  ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#update-device-twins-reported-properties)) and also by sdk ([refernece](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-device-twins)). Both went okay and I did get notifications when I changed the desired properties by back-end services, but with all the desired properties in response. Is there a topic or a function in sdk to just get the properties that where changed? Or to know witch properties were changed without looking through all the desired properties?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a PATCH request to update a desired property in your back-end service. The following screen snippets show an example of the updating only one desired property such as *color*. For quick demonstration purpose, [the Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester) is used:

1. Creating two desired properties (*color*, *abc*):
   [image]
2. *device8* received a changes notification (version=2):
   [image]
3. In this step, we need to update only one desired property (*color*):
   [image]
4. *device8* received a changes notification (version=3) such as the preperty *color*:
   [image]

As you can see in the above pictures, the *device8* subscribed on the topic like you mentioned it. You didn't describe how your backend service updating your desired properties.

Note, that the above example using the REST PATCH call for updating a desired properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've been testing it by just changing the device twins from the portal, which apparently updates the whole desired property. But it's still kinda strange for me that event if you update with unchanged values you still receive the update notification with unchanged properties. Really appreciate your help!